# How can I simplify my solution for "Alternating Sum"?

Tags: python, loops, math

> Alternating Sum is the sum of the numbers in an alternating sequence between the positive and negative integers of the increasing number.
>
> For example, the Alternating Sum of the first 10 numbers is 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 - 6 + 7 - 8 + 9 - 10 = -5.
>
> Alternating Sum of the first 15 numbers is 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 - 6 + 7 - 8 + 9 - 10 + 11 - 12 + 13 - 14 + 15 = 8
>
> Write a program to find the Alternating Sum of the first n when n is a positive integer.
>
> Example Input/Output 1
>
> ```
> Enter n of series: 10
> Alternating Sum from 1 to 10 is -5
> ```
>
> Example Input/Output 2
>
> ```
> Enter n of series: 15
> Alternating Sum from 1 to 15 is 8
> ```

Python code:

```
def altersum(n):
    altersum = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new = -i
            altersum += new
            i += 1
        else:
            altersum += i
            i += 1
    return altersum

n = int(input("Enter n of series: "))
print("Alternating Sum from 1 to {:d} is {:d}".format(n, altersum(n)))
```

It works. I want to make it shorter.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to iterate over all the values from `1` to `n`, you can compute the final sum directly from `n`.

```
def altersum(n):
    if n % 2 == 1:  # odd values are positive
        return (n+1)//2
    else:           # even values are negative
        return -n//2
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be rewritten in one line:

```
altersum = sum(i if i % 2 else -i for i in range(1, n+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop so you don't have to increment `i` yourself.

Instead of checking whether `i` is odd or even, use a multiplier variable that you alternate between `+1` and `-1`.

```
def altersum(n):
    mult = 1
    result = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result += mult * i
        mult *= -1 # flip the sign of multiplier
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

use the builtin `sum` and a generator.

```py
val = input('Enter n of series: ')
val = int(val)
result = sum(i if i % 2 else -i for i in range(1, val + 1))
print(f'Alternating Sum from 1 to {val} is', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of questions are actually mathematical questions. So there are multiple ways to solve the problem.

### Loop

There is the loop approach which already is answered. But still, I'd like to share...

```
def alternating(n):
    the_sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if i % 2:
            the_sum += i
        else:
            the_sum -= i

    return the_sum
```

Please notice `i % 2` returns either `0` or `1` and we use the truthy value of it. So if it is `1` which means `True` it is odd.

### Series

We already know the sum of odd and even numbers can be calculated as:

#### Sum of odds:

```
n ** 2
```

see: https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/sum-of-odd-numbers/

#### Sum of even numbers:

```
n (n + 1)
```

see: https://byjus.com/maths/sum-of-even-numbers/

So our code becomes:

```
def alternating_math(n):
    odds = math.pow((n + 1) // 2, 2)
    evens = n // 2 * (n // 2 + 1)
    return odds - evens
```

Please notice the `n` should be calculated. For odd numbers n is `2 * n + 1 = THE_NUMBER` and for even numbers it is `2 * n = THE_NUMBER`

Note: For huge numbers, the last approach would be faster.

Even a better approach is posted by [Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77070856/find-alternating-sum-python-school-work/77070897#77070897).

Answer (score 0):

The direct computation proposed by @Blckknght is optimum. Here's a fun way to do this by alternating operator functions:

```
from operator import add, sub

op = [sub, add]

N = 15

result = 0

for i in range(1, N+1):
    result = op[i%2](result, i)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
8
```